# Bar-chart Software that displays "Multi-project tasking"?

Tags: gantt-chart

I am looking for a graph-drawing software that produces diagrams that, unlike Gantt-charts, allow to define more that one, independent time-span for one line, because if there is no critical path, one can take up a project, leave it unfinished, start another, and take up the original project at a later time.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Gantt_Chart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

did you try mindview business 3?